# SelectedDate not setting properly on the load in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

> SCinitiationtarget.selectedDate = new
>   Date(rows1[i]['InitiationTarget']);

I am setting my seletedDate in my DateChooser like this. The format i am getting from the Database is 2009-12-30.

Its displaying in correctly.

Comment: Does rows1[i]['InitiationTarget'] trace out as the expected value? what is it's data type?

Comment: Date is the DataType set, when i trace out i get as 2009-12-30 but does not display properly

Comment: is SCinitiationtarget a DateChooser? your post isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution finally.

```
var dateStr:String = dateFormatter.format(rows1[i]['InitiationTarget']);
SCinitiationtarget.selectedDate = new Date(dateStr);

<mx:DateFormatter id="dateFormatter" formatString="MMM D, YYYY"/>
```

With this the problem gets solved.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the date object doesn't recognize the dash as a valid separator. You'll have to some how reformat your date objects.

For example this works:

```
var date:Date = new Date("2009/12/30");
myDateChooser.selectedDate = date;
```

But this doesn't:

```
var date:Date = new Date("2009-12-30");
myDateChooser.selectedDate = date;
```

For more information on what date formats are valid, see the documentation here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Date.html#Date%28%29

Comment: That is what i am looking on how to reformat the date into YYYY/MM/DD as i am getting from the database as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: oldDate.split('-').join('/'); or oldDate.replace(/-/, '/'); (although you'll want to double check my regex pattern in the replace method)

Comment: I suppose that works too, although it's a little odd to post it as a 'solution' to your own question, when it builds upon the other two answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `Date` constructor is called `yearOrTimeValue` and as its documentation says it accepts either year or time in UTC milliseconds. For proper `Date` construction use:

```
new Date(2009, 12, 30)
```

Comment: This isn't completely accurate. From the docs: If you pass one argument of data type String, and the string contains a valid date, the Date object contains a time value based on that date.

Comment: You're right. I just read the documentation of the first argument, which doesn't bring up that use case. Crappy documentation I should say. Anyway it seems that dash is not allowed as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [parse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse%28%29) method of the `Date` class?

```
SCinitiationtarget.selectedDate = Date.parse(rows1[i]['InitiationTarget']);
```